# Why are Time Lords afraid of Cloister if it can't stop a TARDIS from leaving?

Tags: doctor-who

The Cloister attacks people only when people try to leave it, but it was unable to stop TARDIS from leaving. Maybe, the Dalek which was trapped there didn't have emergency temporal shift tech during the Cloister War, but TARDIS is a common thing among Time Lords.

Then, why were Time Lords afraid of Cloister? We can see the emphasis on keeping out of the perimeter. Also, The Doctor ran into the Cloister because Time Lords couldn't pursue him there. The queen (or, whatever) of the Sisterhood of Karn also concluded this easily. Why couldn't Time Lords pursue The Doctor into the Cloister using TARDIS?

Comment: I was under the impression that when the Doctor flew the new TARDIS into the Cloister, it too "kept to the perimeter", which is where Clara was standing with the Sister and the General.

Comment: @MrLister That's not possible. The Cloister couldn't let Clara out.

Answer (score 1):

There was likely never any need for them to ever actually enter the Cloister. It's effectively a hellish 'engine-room' for their "Matrix" computer system. If they want to access the Matrix data they have terminals upstairs to safely use it (as seen a few times in the old Series). They seemed to portray it as a sort of "toxic waste dump" for minds. If someone goes in there, that's ok, but it's designed to make sure they never leave. Not well designed enough obviously. The Doctor got out once as a child, it seems.

They are a notoriously unimaginative lot and probably never thought to use a "time capsule" to safely enter and leave.

One does wonder how they did routine maintenance though. Maybe it was so well designed that it never needed any?

Answer (score 1):

Well when the Doctor went there as a child he did get back, as seen by the Timelords, 'insane' - insinuating it does effect the Timelords greatly. This we found out when he explained it to Clara in Hellbent.

Also, it is said that the Cloisters is where the minds of dead Timelords resided (and even we don't like going around the graveyards where bodies of humans are, imagine if you knew where the souls and minds resided -would you go there?)

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cloisters

However, our beloved Doctor isn't typical representative of his species at all. He pretty much is the rebel who does whatever he wants and thinks is necessary while the others just roll their eyes and hope he will just go away fast. He just dares to do things others won't even consider - like running away to Cloister or pressing the big red button that could destroy his planet and everyone on it.